# Edit a editable label on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [`x-editable`](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to inline edit some text. As long as I click on the label directly everything works fine. But, if I implement a button and want label to be edited on button click, then it won't work.

The reason being, clicking the label edits it and clicking anywhere outside label resets it. Here, when I click the button, its considered as a click outside and editable-label doesn't edit.

*What to do?* I don't want to go with `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines did the trick

I gave the Button a ID ("**inline_editable_button**")

```
jQuery("inline_editable_button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery('#editable_id').editable('toggle');
});
```